# Pandas to_sql fail silently with mssqlserver

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy

When trying to insert a small amount of data into a table in mssql, through a dataframe, the `to_sql()` method shows the number of lines inserted but there is no insertion in the database. I know there are other questions similar to this one, but unfortunately none solve my problem.

This is my code:

*connection*

```
engine = sa.create_engine('mssql://server/db_name?trusted_connection=yes&driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server')
```

*code*

```
conn = engine.connect()

conn.exec_driver_sql("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[my_table] ON")

data_frame.to_sql('[dbo].[my_table]',conn , schema='dbo', if_exists='append', index=False)
```

I am using a local server and windows authentication in this project.

Comment: perhaps you have wrong autocommit setting and your transaction is getting rollbacked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
data_frame.to_sql('[dbo].[my_table]',conn , schema='dbo', if_exists='append', index=False)
```

Should be

```
df.to_sql('my_table',conn , schema='dbo', if_exists='append', index=False)
```

Otherwise it creates and new table in your default schema called "[dbo].[my_table]", and loads it like this:

```
declare @p1 int
--set @p1=4
exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,N'@P1 int',N'INSERT INTO dbo.[[dbo]].[my_table]]] (id) VALUES (@P1)',3
select @p1
```

which creates and loads a new table in your default schema called "[dbo].[my_table]".